# How Can i set selected item in select box list on top at update any detail using spring maven mvc and angularJS

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc

How Can i set selected item in select box list on top at update any detail using spring maven mvc and angularJS on jsp page and my data hold in ng-model

Answer (score 0):

Using Cookies,you can able to set the item as selected.

$cookies.putObject("x",model value);

$cookies.getObject("x");

assign this value of x to your model value.